# Appending a Prefix to Routes in One File in Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am currently refactoring my code and I am hoping there is a more efficient way to make my code look pretty. Here is what I currently have:

```
router.route('/api/merchant/')
        .get(controllerFunction)
        .post(controllerFunction);

router.route('/api/user/')
        .get(controllerFunction)
        .post(controllerFunction);

router.route('/admin/user/')
        .get(controllerFunction)
        .post(controllerFunction);

router.route('/admin/place/')
        .get(controllerFunction)
        .post(controllerFunction);
```

You can see that I have "api" and "admin" as prefixes to certain routes.

I can separate the API route into another file and have the "app.use" middleware append them appropriately, but I was wondering how can I get around this and have these routes in a single file with the main problem being at the end of the file:

> module.exports = router

which only allows me to have one prefix to all my routes.

Comment: This may be a good candidate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com - if your code is already passing tests and functional.

Comment: Neat. I did not know this.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer for your question  follow below

1. You can put your middleware in separate  file.

> [name]Controller.js

```
module.exports = (req, res)=>{
  res.send('I am a middleware');
}
```

2. Create a file bootable routers and **export** an array from routers.

> boot.js

```
const express = require('express'),
  router = express.Router(),
  [name]Controller = require('./controller/[name]Controller'),
  module.exports = [
    router.get('/your path', [name]Controller),
    ...
  ]
```

3. Use router in your app file.

> app.js

```
 const express = require('express'),
     boot = require('./boot'),
     app = express();
     app.use('/prefix', boot);
```

> Now you can use routes with prefix for example:
> localhost:3000/prefix/yourpath

Answer (score 0):

You can mount the whole router on a path. If you do something like:

`router.get('/:id', someFn);`

Then elsewhere you could do:

`app.use('/api', router);`

and the route '/api/:id/` would resolve to the someFn handler

UPDATE

I'm not sure I fully understand your concern, and frankly having all your routes in one file makes for a file longer than I'm comfortable with, but if you really only want to mount one router, you can do something similar to what I described, but inside your routes file.

In that case, you'd still create the multiple routers but then rather than exporting them and mounting on the app, you'd do this:

```
const adminRouter = express.Router();
// configure the admin routes as I described 

const apiRouter = express.Router();
// configure API routes

const main = express.Router();

main.use('/admin', adminRouter);
main.use('/api', apiRouter);

module.exports = main;
```

Comment: I only want to mount a part of the router though. One for "api" and one for "admin"

Comment: Routers are intended as a way to segregate sections of functionality. To do what you want, just make two routers and mount them on different paths.

Comment: Bummer. Was hoping that I could not keep them segregated as a solution.Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Well, keeping them as one file is an option, see mybupdate. Folks tend to dislike that for long term maintenance reasons, though. Ymmv

Answer (score 0):

You can folow below block code, but I suggest you write controler function to another file each for once.

```
        var router = express.Router();
        var useApi = router.route('/user')
                .get(controllerFunction)
                .post(controllerFunction);

        var useAdmin = router.route('/user')
                .get(controllerFunction)
                .post(controllerFunction);

        app.use('/api', userApi);
        app.use('/admin', userAdmin);
```